# Get Boolean from Bus values in Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue component for a [vue multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) within a form. I want to disable/enable this until two other fields have been filled in.

I have accessed that data via bus values inside my component but when I try to use it I never get a true or false answer as expected.

I am trying to update the `disabled` attribute with `enableKeywords` which is controlled by `selectedTopic && questionTitle`, both of these values come from the root or another component and I can see their data updated in the root of this component via Vue dev tools.

**Multiselect Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <multiselect 
    v-model="internalValue" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Search" 
label="name" track-by="id" :options="options" :multiple="true" :disabled="enableKeywords">
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
  export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    props: ['value'],
    data () {
      return {
        internalValue: this.value,
        options: [],
        selectedTopic: null,
        questionTitle: null,
        enableKeywords: selectedTopic && questionTitle
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      axios.get('/vuekeywords').then(response => this.options = response.data);
      bus.$on("send-topic", selectedTopic => this.selectedTopic = selectedTopic);
      bus.$on("send-title", questionTitle => this.questionTitle = questionTitle);
    },
    watch: {
      internalValue(v){
        bus.$emit('send-keywords', v);
        this.$emit('input', v);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think this would just be `:disabled="!(selectedTopic && questionTitle)"`

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I thought it would be but I had the wrong syntax. I didn't realise it needed to be wrapped in parenthesis. Please add as an answer and I'll accept. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `disabled` to be true when either of the properties you want is not populated, you should negate the boolean, `selectedTopic && questionTitle`.

```
:disabled="!(selectedTopic && questionTitle)"
```

Answer (score 2):

The bus has two event attached, $emit & $on.
$on receiving the two parameters, then toggle your `enableKeywords` to `true`

Comment: So use a method with an if statement to determine whether enableKeywords is true or false? Thanks

Comment: `enableKeywords` is controlled by two other elements right? if these two are not empty then `enableKeywords` is true. 

You can set it to true, on the $on event, considering that you're $emit these two other values